# Use arrow functions in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, arrow-functions

I am writing a jQuery plugin. But it doesn't seem to work when I use arrow function to extend jQuery.

This works :

```
$.fn.extend({
    func: function (params) {
        var ob = $(this);
        var selector = $(this).selector;
        var defaults = {

        };

        params = $.extend(defaults, params);

        generate(ob, selector, params);
    }
});
```

But when I try to use arrow function, it returns me the `window` object :

```
$.fn.extend({
    func: (params) => {
        var ob = $(this); // returns window object
        var selector = $(this).selector;
        var defaults = {

        };

        params = $.extend(defaults, params);

        generate(ob, selector, params);
    }
});
```

I've also tried using `this.currentTarget` but it returns `undefined`.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ??

Comment: This is expected. Regular function has `this` pointing to jquery object, and arrow function has root `this` context.

Comment: care to explain the downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because different rules apply to arrow functions when it comes to binding `this`.

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or
>   `new.target`.

See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more information.