# Addition of new methods to node.js http.ServerResponse.prototype not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, prototype, middleware

As part of my learning of Node internals, I'm trying to add some basic functions to the Node response prototype without requiring some external libraries. It shouldn't be a difficult task, however, the response is never passed to the new functions and can never be retrieved through the *this* statement. This is an example to bind a template render function to the server response.

```
const http = require('http');

const newMethods = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype);

newMethods.render = async (view, data) => {
    const renderResult = await aTemplateLibray(view, data);
    this.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    this.end(renderResult);
}
// Other methods here...

// Then
Object.assign(http.ServerResponse.prototype, newMethods);

module.exports = http;
```

Once I use this http server, I can use the new render function, but the response is not passed to it, so an error message is thrown, something like **this.writeHead is not a function**.

I also tried with the Object.defineProperty method.

```
Object.defineProperty(http.ServerResponse.prototype, 'render', 
    {writable: true,
     enumerable: true,
     get: return this.socket.parser.incoming
    });
```

I found some old library that returned that socket with the old **__defineGetter__** method and I test it with the new form, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: The first version doesn't make a lot of sense (there's no point creating the object, adding the property, and then *copying* that property to the prototype), and moreover uses an arrow function, so of course `this` is not what you expect (more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704847/use-arrow-functions-in-jquery-plugin), though there's a better one somewhere). The `defineProperty` version won't even parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is your use of the arrow function expression (`=>`), which has particular consequences with regards to what `this` points to inside the function (more on that [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)).

In your case, you want to use `async function(...)`:

```
newMethods.render = async function(view, data) {
    const renderResult = await aTemplateLibray(view, data);
    this.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    this.end(renderResult);
}
```